# WebView: Bad Request when loading a url

Tags: android, webview

When I am trying to load a URL, in a WebView:

```
private final WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
};
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
webView.loadUrl("https://post.craigslist.org/");
```

I get this html on the page:

> **Bad Request**
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

[image]

There is nothing in the `onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)` callback as well.

Comment: can you please let me know the android API version on which you're testing it?

Comment: @Deminem `API-19` with manifest set to `android:targetSdkVersion="18"`. But I have checked the [WebView migration for 4.4](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html) and none of those changes seem to effect my code.

Comment: I just wanted to check if it's an earlier android API version. Because `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` does not get invoked if the URL source is a redirect for (Android version < 3.0). Based on your given settings, I have just tested and it works perfectly fine without any issues. Btw, why are you trying to load the url twice? You don't need to load url inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method until you do something specific on URL filtering.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc- Tested working on both 4.4.2 and 4.4.4 without any issues. However, the web page itself contains some errors. `[INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: https://www.craigslist.org/js/general-concat.min.js?v=c7551eda9664705c434eac8c09bcd83a (8)`

Answer (score 2):

It is giving you this error because you are not handling redirects correctly from this webpage
try this

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
    // do your handling codes here, which url is the requested url
    // probably you need to open that url rather than redirect:
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return false; // then it is not handled by default action
 }
});
```

Comment: I tried that. The thing is, it never reaches `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
public class WebPageLoader extends Activity
 {

   final Activity activity = this;
   private String html;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview.loadUrl("https://post.craigslist.org/");

       webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
     });

     webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

this to

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
}
```

I hope this will help you.

**Update**

```
mWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView1);
if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches())
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);      

webClient = new WebViewClient() {       

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFormResubmission(WebView view, Message dontResend,
            Message resend) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onFormResubmission(view, dontResend, resend);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        if (url.contains("purchasehistory.html")) {
            mURLNavigation.onURLNavigation(3);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
};

WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(webClient);
```

This code works for me..

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to keep the API level number when you get this kind of problem.

For example, in API 19 the function shouldOverrideUrlLoading fails to call check this, http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

Note: 
shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not called when loading a url like

loadUrl("http://google.com")

and also Redirect does not work on API Level 11 and lower. (As you replied to Abdul, it is not called )

Use a workaround: I mean override onPageStarted which works on all versions. But, only thing is it is called bit later.

Strictly Random work around :

Use WebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true) on Android 4.1.1, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you load a url in a WebView:

```
private WebView URL

URL = (WebView) WebDialog.findViewById(R.id.url1);  
URL.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
URL.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);  
URL.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);  
URL.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
URL.getSettings().setUserAgentString("My URL");  
URL.loadUrl("//the first url goes here");
```

You need to then build a layout similar to this as an xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/ticketline"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/Title"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        webview.loadUrl("http://route.izooto.com/?id=1563543&client=41882&rid=4188273230385&frwd=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbT91dG1fc291cmNlPWl6b290byZ1dG1fbWVkaXVtPXB1c2hfbm90aWZpY2F0aW9ucyZ1dG1fY2FtcGFpZ249VGVzdCBpWm9vdG8gTFAmdXRtX2NvbnRlbnQ9JnV0bV90ZXJtPQ==&bkey=f9_DIVuweYA:APA91bFE9x7PN6J5Oy67NypwlT8ZT3Qgz0VSYtCT4_DH5v4l7mCsY7q3aqSrOh6mCcWKIjz4aRiOWQ8ap85r85vHiTh3Mc8n4MiHSnbMXUKGB_5HkDjiBCQg5a7IQifvrakl7bIXF_oA");
       WebViewClient webClient = new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFormResubmission(WebView view, Message dontResend,
                                           Message resend) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onFormResubmission(view, dontResend, resend);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                if (url.contains("purchasehistory.html")) {
                   // mURLNavigation.onURLNavigation(3);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
        };

        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(webClient);
```

Comment: Please try to add context to your answer, and how it solves the problem